# Erro: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a method that instantiates 2 objects of the same entity, example:

```
MyObj entity = this.search(id);
MyObj entityNew = new MyObj();
BeanUtils.copyProperties(entity, entityNew, "id");
```

In the course of the method, I update some fields of the 'entity' object and order it to be updated, with 'entityNew' I register it as if it were a new record in the database.

But it is throwing the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: br.com.meuprojeto.model.TermoDoacaoEquipamento.TermoDoacaoEquipamentoEntity.implementos
```

[Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6H8d.png)

Does anyone know how to resolve?
After some research, I saw that this is caused due to entity A setting the same values as a collection to entity B. But I don't know how to resolve this, and I'm just working with just one entity "MyObj" (fictitious name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its because of the bean. Its of singleton type so it gets confused as they have the same reference. You can instead try doing it this way:

```
MyObj entityNew = (MyObj) BeanUtils.cloneBean(entity);
```

Comment: I tried to do it the way mentioned, but I don't see the method option "cloneBean()", only copyProperties and others. Forgot to mention, but I'm using Spring Web and Spring Data JPA modules.

Comment: I think alternatively you can write a method to set the required properties to the entityNew object.
Like: entityNew.setId(entity.getId());

Comment: I found out what was going on. In my entity there was another collection that was coming empty, then in BeanUtils I think it was trying to copy the empty collection from instance A to instance B.

    if (!entity.getTermos().isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < entity.getTermos().size(); i++) {
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(entity.getTermos().get(i), 
        entityNew.getTermos().get(i), "termos");
       }
} else {
    entityNew.setTermos(new ArrayList<>());
}

I solved it by putting another check in the method for this collection.

Thanks for the help Millind!